# How to convert build file .exe format in .scr?

Tags: c#

I have a build output in .exe format How can I save more and .scr?
Many times I saw people collected in their assemblies .bat format .scr, e.t.c

Answer (score 7):

The Windows Screensaver files are just normal executables, so you can just rename the .exe file to .scr and it will work.

Comment: Also note that you should handle some command-line arguments: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/182383

Comment: Renaming an existing `scr` file to an `exe` and running it gets the screen saver options in most cases.